# Do we need separate tags for Layer Files (*.lyr) and Layer Definition Files (*.qlr)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

From [Does QGIS have the equivalent of ArcGIS's Layer (*.LYR) file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88834/does-qgis-have-the-equivalent-of-arcgiss-layer-lyr-file) my understanding is that these two file types can be considered equivalent in functionality:

- Layer File (*.lyr) of ArcGIS for Desktop
- Layer Definition File (*.qlr) of QGIS

There are currently tags for each:

- [layer-file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layer-file) with 50 questions

> A file with a .lyr extension that stores the path to a source dataset
>   and other layer properties, including symbology.

- [layer-definition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layer-definition) with 1 question

> layer-definition stores information about a layer in a file that can
>   be re-added to a project

Do we need both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [layer-definition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layer-definition) should be made a synonym of [layer-file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layer-file), and have its tag wiki updated to something like:

> Layer (`*.lyr`) or Layer Definition (`*.qlr`) File that stores path to 
>   source dataset and other layer properties, including symbology, for
>   ArcGIS and QGIS respectively.

Some data:

- Of the 50 questions tagged [layer-file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layer-file), 29 are co-tagged [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) and 5 are co-tagged [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis)
- Of the 1 question tagged [layer-definition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layer-definition), 0 are co-tagged [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) and 1 is co-tagged [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis)
- Of the 789 questions tagged [layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layers), 133 are co-tagged [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) and 211 are co-tagged [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis)

If it works for QGIS layers and ArcGIS layers to be tagged the same, and just distinguished by product co-tagging, then I think it should work equally well for QGIS layer definition files and ArcGIS layer files.

I favour [layer-file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layer-file) being the master and [layer-definition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layer-definition) being the synonym because it is a crisper term, the functionality has been present for a lot longer and is thus better known, and it currently has 50 times the usage.  I think it is also much less likely to get confused with the unrelated [definition-query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition-query) tag (that has 72 questions).

Comment: This has been implemented.